# Documentation on the SQL execution plan page in Oracle Enterprise Manager (Oracle 10g)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

In Oracle Enterprise Manager, in "Performance > Top Activity", you can click a SQL that is being executed and then go to the Plan tab to see SQL execution plan.

For the execution plan, the Enterprise Manager shows a table with the execution plan steps. That table has the following columns:

```
Operation   Object  Object Type Order   Rows    Size (KB)   Cost    Time (sec)  CPU Cost    I/O Cost
```

I'd like to understand the meaning of each one of these columns, but I did not find any documentation on this.

Can you recommend me any document or explain the meaning of the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These columns are all coming from the [V$SQL_PLAN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2120.htm#REFRN30250) table, so you can use the documentation for that view.  The documentation is somewhat limited, however, because exactly how the optimizer makes some of these estimates is *very* complicated, depending on the specific operation, system statistics, object statistics, and optimizer parameters among other things.  And every version of Oracle will likely calculate things a bit differently because the optimizer group is constantly tweaking their formulas.  Jonathan Lewis's [Cost-Based Oracle Fundamentals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590596366) is the most comprehensive source for learning exactly how the optimizer costs different operations.